# Exchange 2010 - transport server not sending emails to internal Exchange server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have a problem whereby the transport server has stopped processing the queue to the internal mail server. (inbound emails).

The exchange server has been offline for a few hours due to a problem with the vm's hardware.

All issues resolved, I can check send email, receive internal email and I can see external mails coming into the transport servers queue.

Is there a way to rejoin/refresh it.  I've obviously tried to retry the messages without any joy.

Any advice appreciated. I'm not exchange expert.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: I've had a similar problem where the Edge Server role was on a TMG server. I resolved it by removing and re-adding the Edge Subcription - I didn't have the time to troubleshoot it any further.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has similar issues, the problem was caused by a migration using Veeam backup and replication.

Veeam appears to replace the mac addresses of the nics making Windows believe there are new network adapters in the VM.  Windows then by default uses DHCP to pick up a new IP address, leaving the actual IP address assigned to an adapter you cannot see in guest OS.

By assigning the correct IP and overriding the DHCP setting, windows prompts you to remove IP info from the invisible NIC.

The next issue was caused by dns caching. In the end this was resolved by flushing the dns cache on edge server. `ipconfig /flushdns`. Once this was done, mail flow was resumed.

Hope it helps.

Sam